# What is the key when the client want to get a session id in SSL

Tags: tls, session-management

According to the abbreviated handshake protocol, the client hello will contains a session id if it knows one. So my question here is: what is the key for a client to find session id if it is talking with multiple hosts and using multiple client certificate?

Comment: Hostname of the server when connecting to different host.

Answer (score 1):

The abbreviated handshake is used in re-establishing a previously agreed secure connection, which means it will use the same keys as it used for the previous session where a full handshake was used to initiate the connection and agree on the keys and ciphers etc. See [Speeding up SSL: Enabling session reuse](http://vincent.bernat.im/en/blog/2011-ssl-session-reuse-rfc5077.html)